# AJAX FilteredTextBoxExtender allow carriage return

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, filtering

I have a multi-line text box that I am using an AJAX FilteredTextBoxExtender to limit the user input to only numbers. I'd like to also allow the user to add a new line by using the enter key.  I've searched and haven't found anything that works.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code for reference:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEIDEntryBox" runat="server" CssClass="PrettyEntryBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="300px" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbeEID"
            runat="server"
            TargetControlID="txtEIDEntryBox"
            FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add Custom to the FilterType and then add the following in the
>   code-behind:
>
> ```
> Protected Sub filter_IdentifierFilter_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles filter_IdentifierFilter.Init
>     filter_IdentifierFilter.ValidChars = filter_IdentifierFilter.ValidChars & vbCrLf
> End Sub
> ```

via http://forums.asp.net/t/1203820.aspx/1

Comment: Holy hell is question is old. But thanks for grave digging and posting this!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible, i would suggest using jQuery, there is a good answer [here](http://www.codeasp.net/forums/asp-net-topics/clent-side-web-development/673/enter-key-doesn-t-work-in-ajax-filteredextender-control)

```
$.fn.filterTextBox = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                    return (
                            key == 13 || //enter
                            (key >= 37 && key <= 40) || //arrows
                            (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || //numbers
                            key == 8 || //backspace
                            key == 9 || //tab
                            key == 46 //delete
                            );
                });
            });
        };

        $(function() {
            $('#<%= txtEIDEntryBox.ClientID %>').filterTextBox();
        });
```

Comment: After a couple more days of searching, this seems to be the closest answer. It takes a little more hacking because the code above does not allow the numpad or other keys that should be allowed.